# Proving amount of Monero - Range Proofs

Tags: range-proofs

As far as i understand Monero currently uses range proofs (Soon to be bulletproofs) to prove that when an amount of Monero is sent that amount is between 0 and some large number. this is to protect against negative amounts being sent

My question is can Monero range proofs or bulletproofs for that matter prove that a public key owns a certain amount of Monero. for example can i create a construction that a third party can verify that i have say between 50 and 100 XMR

As far as my research goes the only way to prove balance in accounts is to provide view keys and a set of signed key images to a third party, is this still the only way to do this?

Looking forward to any input
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to know a wallet's balance using only the public key in what is meant to be a private and secure cryptocurrency ?

Comment: No, im asking if there is a way that you can voluntarily provide a proof that you have an amount in your wallet without having to reveal what amount that is. I just want to prove that the balance that belongs to x wallet is between a range. wondering if theres a way to leverage range proofs to do this.

Comment: Ok. There is currently no way of doing this to my knowledge. View keys aren't really meant for giving to a third party.. they are more about a way for you to check your funds (by creating a view only wallet) when you have a separate cold wallet etc. What you are describing sounds like it is meant for a specific use case aimed at increasing the commercial applications of Monero (+1 for that) but I'm not sure that leveraging range proofs or bulletproofs would be the best way to go about this as it requires computation

Comment: @KamLazar You  might be interested in this idea from stoffu: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/7mkoi8/random_question/druqe05/

Comment: Yeah im thinking this is the way to go. i just wanted to check with some of the guys from MRL and the community to ensure that there isn't a way to prove a custom range with range proofs or bulletproofs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, I think it's possible to use the range proof scheme (whether using Borromean or Bulletproofs) to prove that the amount committed by a given Pedersen Commitment falls within a certain range. A Pedersen Commitment `C` committing to an amount `a` using a mask (aka. blinding factor) `x` is represented as

```
C = x*G + a*H
```

where `G` and `H` are protocol-defined independent base points. The range proof scheme proves that the committed amount in `C` falls between `0` and `2^64-1`. To prove that the committed amount falls between a specific range, say 50 and 100 XMR, we could define two more commitments

```
C1 = C - 50*H
C2 = 100*H - C
```

and generate a new range proof for each of `C1` and `C2`.

This approach could be generalized to involve multiple outputs and prove that the sum of the committed amounts falls within a specified range. For auditing purposes, however, I think it's more useful to prove "I hold at least this amount in my wallet" rather than proving "My holding falls within this range". Such a proof scheme called "reserve proof" is currently being developed (https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3027).

See also: [Using Monero as proof of funds](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/using-monero-as-proof-of-funds)